# If statement with a whole list of things inside it

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Im struggling on a formula:

```
=IF(B5=75,IF(B4<2.5, ROUND(SUM(B3/B2)+1,0),0,0),)
```

if b7 equals 75, then if B4 is less than 2.5, divide b3 by b2 and round it up to the next whole number then add 1, or if b4 if larger than 2.5 return 0 or is b5 is not "75" then return 0

so a correct result  would be:

```
B4=2.4
B5=75
```

B3(2.0) devided by B2(.04) rounded up to nearest whole number =6 plus 1 =7

Thank you for your time. Looking forward to the help, its driving me insane!

Comment: for reading purposes put spaces, new lines or indentations to improve readability it should then be clear.

Comment: Think I have managed this now thanks to anyone that has had a bash at it. But now im after basically the same formula but need b5 to be within a range of bigger than2.5 but less than 3.0 if this is possible

Comment: =IF(B5=75,IF(B4<2.5, ROUND(SUM(B3/B2)+1,0),0),0) this is what I got to work thanks.

Comment: =IF(B5=75,IF((B4>2.4,B4<3.0), ROUND(SUM(B3/B2)+1,0),0),0)    

I need is b4 is greater than 2.4 but less than 3.0 to do runs the formula, else 0.

I haver tried everything I can think of, Please Help me. Thanks Adam

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a one heeding [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(B5=75, IF(B4<2.5, ROUND(SUM(B3/B2)+1, 0), 0), 0)
```

...is what you got to work

then:

```
=IF(B5=75, IF((B4>2.4)*(B4<=3), ROUND(SUM(B3/B2)+1, 0), 0), 0)
```

Comment: Yeah managed to get this working thanks, now im struggling on the "range"

If b4 is > 2.4 and <=3.0 not sure how to make it work, it keeps closing the if statement on me?

Comment: Just inserted it and it works a treat thanks so much! really appreciate your time! Hope your keeping well!

Comment: Just donated to you. Not much but its all that was in my pal account appreciate your help Adam